# label doesn't appear on dynamically created form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, label

I'm staring at my code for hours now and I don't understand what's going on. I'm creating a form with a number of checkboxes and labels, based on a textbox value from another form.

This is the code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim lb As Label
    Dim cb1 As CheckBox
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


    For i = 1 To CInt(Aantal.Text) - 1
        indivwoningen.Width = indivwoningen.Size.Width + 21
        indivwoningen.Button1.Location = New Point(indivwoningen.Button1.Location.X + 21, indivwoningen.Button1.Location.Y)

        lb = New Label
        indivwoningen.Controls.Add(lb)
        lb.Text = i + 1
        lb.Font = indivwoningen.Label23.Font
        lb.Location = New Point(indivwoningen.Label23.Location.X + 21 * i, indivwoningen.Label23.Location.Y)

        For j = 1 To 18
            cb1 = New CheckBox
            indivwoningen.Controls.Add(cb1)
            cb = indivwoningen.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & j & "00", False)(0)
            cb1.Location = New Point(cb.Location.X + 21 * i, cb.Location.Y)
            cb1.Width = cb.Width
            cb1.Text = cb.Text
            If i < 10 Then
                cb1.Name = "CheckBox" & j & "0" & i
            Else
                cb1.Name = "CheckBox" & j & i
            End If
        Next
    Next
    indivwoningen.Show()

End Sub
```

The created form has got two flaws:

- Only the first created label is visible
- The checkboxes aren't properly aligned.

I don't understand what's going on. Can someone help me?

EDIT: Here are pictures before I create extra controls and after

[image: http://s21.postimg.org/552yty213/Knipsel.png]
[image]

Comment: you need to add it to the form's controls collection: `me.Controls.Add(cb1)`

Comment: i do that for both the label (lb) and the checkboxes (cb1). The checkboxes are all visible on the form, but they aren't aligned. I tried to post pictures, but i can't. The first column of checkboxes is already built into the form. I create extra columns that need to have the same Y position but different X positions, only the Y position isn't the same.

Comment: sorry, missed where it was

Comment: its probably creating one less of each than you want also.  Debug it.  Check that when `i = 2` the label location is something different than when `i=1`  they might be on top of each other.  I dont know what "properly aligned" means for the second question.

Comment: I've uploaded some images. I already checked if the labels were created by putting a messagebox after the creation that stated the text, location and font of the label. It's strange that the first label (nr. 2) is visible but the others aren't.

Comment: instead of Controls.Find, create a Point var you use to set the Check locations.  the first time thru is probably wrong.  Also turn on OPTION STRICT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Autosize` property to True for the labels and set the `Height` of the checkboxes to the same height of your reference checkbox

```
For i = 1 To CInt(Aantal.Text) - 1
    ....
    lb = New Label
    indivwoningen.Controls.Add(lb)
    lb.Text = i + 1
    lb.Font = indivwoningen.Label23.Font
    lb.Autosize = True
    lb.Location = New Point(indivwoningen.Label23.Location.X + 21 * i, indivwoningen.Label23.Location.Y)

    For j = 1 To 18
        cb1 = New CheckBox
        indivwoningen.Controls.Add(cb1)
        cb = indivwoningen.Controls.Find("CheckBox" & j & "00", False)(0)
        cb1.Location = New Point(cb.Location.X + 21 * i, cb.Location.Y)
        cb1.Width = cb.Width
        cb1.Height = cb.Height
        cb1.Text = cb.Text
        If i < 10 Then
            cb1.Name = "CheckBox" & j & "0" & i
        Else
            cb1.Name = "CheckBox" & j & i
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Well, for the checkbox the explanation seems to be easy. The new checkbox has, by default, an Heigth of 24 pixels while the one drawn on the form as a smaller Height. So, because the check square is centered inside the Height of the Checkbox it appears to be not aligned to the reference checkbox.

For the labels the problem is of the same kind. Without setting the `Autosize`, the labels are created with a default size of 100x23 pixels. This means that the label with text "2" extends its size to cover the position of the labels with text "3","4","5","6", while the label with text "3" covers the label with text "7" and so on.

In any case setting `AutoSize` seems to be the default behavior, followed also in the `Form.Designer.vb` file where the controls are created following your design time instructions.

You could also try to set the Size of the dynamically created labels to the same size of the reference label and the effect is the same.

Comment: Thank you! I don't remember that i've changed the height of the checkboxes in the first column. Strange...

Comment: Probably not, I think it is the designer that draws the checkbox smaller, while the dynamically ones are taller